# How to prove that preimage of measurable space is measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Given a function mapping between two sample spaces $S_1$ and $S_2$, if $S_2$,$F_2$ is measurable how do I show that preimage of $S_2$,$F_2$ in $S_1$ is measurable set?

Comment: LaTeX works, you must just stop editing for a while so that it will be applied to preview window.

Comment: For LaTeX, enclose terms in $ signs.

Comment: Got it. Which tag can I use for multiline latex block?

Comment: The align environment will work, but use \newline instead of \\.

Comment: how do I use align environment? Is it a tag?

Comment: Several points: 1. See my edits as to how to use Latex. 2. You may also want to see this thread: [Vote early, vote often](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/314/vote-early-vote-often). 3. If this is homework could you please tag it as such so that people can provide hints instead of complete answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is trivial: the preimage of $(S_2, F_2)$ is all of $S_1$ (by definition), which is measurable (by definition).

Perhaps you want to conclude that the preimage of any *measurable subset* of $S_2$ is measurable: that is a nice property of a function.  However, this conclusion is not true in general, either.  For example, let $(S_1, F_1)$ contain a nonmeasurable set and let $(S_2, F_2)$ contain two disjoint measurable atoms.  Map every element of the nonmeasurable set to one of the atoms and map every element of the complement of the nonmeasurable set to the other atom.  The preimage of the first atom is not measurable, whence this map is not measurable.

Comment: Yes its trivial. I was able to come up with a simple proof using sigma algebra.